# How to pass url image from parent to child components in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I use props to send an  object {url :'blabla',name :'' ,price:'' } from the parent to child components in vus js, but the problem is I cant use url image in the child. it doesn't show.
the name and price work normal

Comment: how does the url of your image look like?

Comment: ok when I use a strict url like this <img src ="./../../assets/images/nike/1.jpg" it's work normal. but when I use dynamique data like this <img :src="image" > and my data is like this data:() =>({    image : "./../../assets/images/nike/1.jpg"   }) doesn't work. the same thing when I use slider library always a problem of url image

Comment: Can you provide your code? We can´t reproduce the problem your explain without some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question ain't constructive enough but I think I understand what youre trying to do.
To pass image as props to a child component, you need to import it in the Parent component script, then you can bind to it by passing it as props to the child component in the parent's template:

```
// PARENT COMPONENT
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildComponent 
     :logo="logoObject"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from '../<point to child component here>'
  import logo from '../../asset/<point to image here>'
  export default(){
  data(){
    logoObject: logo
  }
}
</script>

// CHILD COMPONENT
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="logo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default(){
 props: ['logo']
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes this is exacetly what i did. but when i use this props in :src='log' it doesn't work. so my friend here tell me to use require so I create a  function return require(logo).

Comment: Ok, perhaps if you can share your implementation @Omar Gr

Comment: in your child component  <img :src="getImgUrl(logo)" .  getImgUrl(logo){ return require('path'+logo)  . I hope to work for you